# Yield and revenue optimisation of a field: Can Timefold calculate that?

Tags: optimization, yield, timefold, revenue

Here is a real life scenario and I wanted to know if TimeFold is relevant for that:

I would like to maximize the yield over years of a land to be planted with 2 species of olive trees.
I have 2 species of olive trees and 50,000m2 of land.
Species 1, called Zelmati, costs 8eur and produces 500g of olives after 5 years and doubles every two years for 12 years before reaching a maximum production which lasts 2000 years.
Species 2, called Spanish, costs 25eur and produces 300g after 2 years and doubles every year to reach a maximum after 5 and runs out after 20 years.
When species 2 becomes exhausted after 20 years, it is possible to replace it with species 2 or with species 1.

How to maximize the profit made after 10, 20, 30, 40 and 60 years depending on the capital invested in each species ?

I haven't tried anything yet :) I am a noob

Answer (score 0):

I would divide the 50,000m2 in pieces of for example 1000m² and assign them at that granularity. Each of those is a instance of the class LandAssignment (a planning entity).

Next, assign each LandAssigment a SpeciesStrategy (that the only planning variable).

Some examples of SpeciesStrategy

- plant olives forever
- plant olives until they run out (20y) then plant carrots
- ...

You can do it much more fine grained (smaller land pieces) or more dynamic (to avoid many combinations in SpeciesStrategy), but that could be overkill. And explode the search space.

Comment: If you can choose per 1m², and your constraints allow it, a linear programming solver might be a better fit.

Comment: thanks for Geoffrey De Smet for having a look. So that seems doable. Do you have any example that may be relevant for me so I can start modeling and experimenting?
What does a Strategy look like in term of implementation? 
1m² is indeed maybe not relevant .... oh I just realised that I forgot to mention another variable in the problem, I lost it in google translate: species 1 occupies 50m2 of land and species 2 occupies 9m2 .